# Mongoose find all elements that matches field plus any object in list (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't find how to get all documents that matches by critera.
I have 1 field called Id:

`parent = 1`

And a list with these combinations:

```
[
  { year: 2021, month: 1 },
  { year: 2021, month: 0 },
  { year: 2020, month: 11 },
  { year: 2020, month: 10 }
]
```

The documents looks like this:

```
id: Id
parent: Id
year: Number
month: Number
```

And I'm trying to find ALL documents that matches parent and where month and year both matches ANY 1 from the list.

Any idea? I've tried with elemMatch but with no success.

```js
const foundDocuments = await Document.find({
    parent, results: { $elemMatch: { list } },
});
```

example data:

```json
[
    {id: 4, parent: 1, year: 2021, month: 5 },
    {id: 5, parent: 1, year: 2021, month: 4 },
    {id: 6, parent: 1, year: 2021, month: 3 },
    {id: 7, parent: 1, year: 2021, month: 2 },
    {id: 8, parent: 1, year: 2021, month: 1 },
    {id: 9, parent: 1, year: 2021, month: 0 },
    {id: 10, parent: 1, year: 2020, month: 11 },
    {id: 11, parent: 1, year: 2020, month: 10 },
    {id: 12, parent: 1, year: 2020, month: 9 },
    {id: 13, parent: 2, year: 2021, month: 1 },
    {id: 14, parent: 2, year: 2021, month: 0 },
    {id: 15, parent: 2, year: 2020, month: 11 },
    {id: 16, parent: 2, year: 2020, month: 10 },
    {id: 17, parent: 2, year: 2020, month: 9 },
]
```

expected output:

```json
[
    {id: 8, parent: 1, year: 2021, month: 1 },
    {id: 9, parent: 1, year: 2021, month: 0 },
    {id: 10, parent: 1, year: 2020, month: 11 },
]
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your data and the expected output?

Comment: Added data and expected, hope that clarifies my issue a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using JS you can create the query to add all pair values into a list like this:

```js
const list = [
    { year: 2021, month: 1 },
    { year: 2021, month: 0 },
    { year: 2020, month: 11 },
    { year: 2020, month: 10 }
  ]
const parentId = 1

var findObj = {
  parent:parentId, 
  $or:list.map(m => {
    return {year:m.year,month:m.month}
  })
}
console.log(findObj)
```

Here the find object is the same as used in this [example query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LfCJUbqd8MI) so you only need to add into a query

```
const foundDocuments = await Document.find(findObj);
```

Note how the trick in the query is to do an `$or` with all possible pair values. Also, your expected output does not include id `11`. Is that a mistake?